# jQuery ajax returns 400 bad request when trying to send an object which has another object as a property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am making the following ajax request using jQuery:

```
var obj = {
        'id': id,
        'client' : client,
        'amount' : amount,
        'addressFrom' : addressFrom,
        'addressTo' : addressTo,
        'date': date
    };

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: "/saveOrUpdateOrder",
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success : function(data, status) {
            refreshPage(data);
        },
    });
```

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrUpdateOrder", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String saveOrUpdateOrder(Model model, @RequestBody Order order) {
        log.info("/jquery order controller -> saveOrUpdateOrder");
        // some other actions
}
```

Here are classes Order an Client:

```
public class Order {
    private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private Client client;
    private Integer amount;
    private String addressFrom;
    private String addressTo;

    public Order() {
        date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        amount = 0;
    }

    // setters and getters
}

public class Client {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private Integer amount;
    private Date lastOrder;

    public Client() {
        amount = 0;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

I also have my own ClientEditor because I'm sending 'id' as a 'client' in the object 'obj' in ajax request:

```
@Component("clientEditor")
public class ClientEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ClientService clientService;

    public ClientEditor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        Client client = clientService.getClientById(Long.valueOf(text));
        setValue(client);
    }

}
```

And in my controller I have this:

```
@Autowired(required = true)
    private ClientEditor clientEditor;

    @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Client.class, clientEditor);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
            sdf.setLenient(true);
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
            binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
        }
```

When I did the same without ajax, only using form with `action = "/saveOrUpdateOrder"` it worked fine. But when I'm trying to send json using ajax I always have 400 bad request as a result. I guess the problem is in getting an Order from JSON data.
I tried to switch off ClientEditor and send an object like this

```
var client = {
        'id': clientId
    }

    var obj = {
        'id': id,
        'client' : client,
        'amount' : amount,
        'addressFrom' : addressFrom,
        'addressTo' : addressTo,
        'date': date
    };
```

But it didn't work either. And I tried client variable with full parameters too. What's the problem? How to do it right?

Comment: Do you have the jackson json library in your classpath?

Comment: How does your raw JSON data look like when sent by the browser?

Comment: Could you show what you send with the form action ?

Comment: That is how it looks like when I send id as client:`{"id":"61","client":"41","amount":44,"addressFrom":"Akhmatova str 35","addressTo":"Harkivs'ke sh. 19","date":"02.10.2015 11:37"}`

Comment: And when I'm trying to send client as an object: `{"id":"3","client":{"id":"7"},"amount":200,"addressFrom":"address from","addressTo":"new address to","date":"17.09.2015 02:50"}`

Comment: Form is made like this `<form:form action="saveOrUpdateOrder" method="post" modelAttribute="order" onsubmit="checkOrdersFields(); return false;">`

Comment: And when I sent data on submit button directly from form without json (and it worked) I had `@ModelAttribute` annotation in controller method instead of `@RequestBody` annotation I have now.

Comment: About jackson json library. I'm a little bit confused here. I don't think I use it at all... I'm new with all that web stuff, just trying to do some common examples to understand how it all works.

Comment: I looked through and I found jackson dependency in my maven project, is that it?

Comment: Tried to change annotation on `@ModelAttribute("order") @RequestBody Order order`. Finally I'm not getting Bad request! But I now get an order with all parameters = `null`

Comment: And I don't get bad reaquest with annotation `@ModelAttribute Order order`. But I still get an empty order.